# Why do different browsers require their own border radius style?

Tags: css, browser, webkit, cross-browser, gecko

I've wondered this for a while. Why do different browsers only support the CSS border-radius property if it is prefixed with their own special prefix. I don't understand why I have to write this:

```
/* For Firefox and other Gecko browsers */
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
/* For Chrome/Safari and other Webkit browsers */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
/* For others */
border-radius: 5px;
```

When I could just write this:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

Is there a reason that I'm required to write the prefixes? Why don't the browsers all just support the `border-radius` property? It just doesn't make sense to me, why browser developers decided to all have different properties that just make my life harder. Is there a technical or legal reason behind it?

Comment: Because they don't natively support them with a standard terminology? You're preaching to the choir, btw.

Comment: I was more so wondering if there was a technical or legal reason behind it all.

Comment: It's just about standards compliance. `border-radius` is part of CSS3 and newer Webkit browsers support CSS3 so they no longer need the `-webkit` prefix.

Comment: There was no standard "border-radius property" until css3, so browsers couldn't just support the border-radius property.

Comment: @S0lder: It's technical. As Jared already said, they don't support the standard terminology. Typically this is because they don't support the standard fully. You've given a *very* basic example which does look exactly the same, but if you were doing something more complex, then this would show up.

Comment: Well, the `border-radius crew©` does think they own it, but hey, they can't occupy that forever, eh? `;)`

Comment: The better answer is that browser vendors added a browser-specific notation so that they could later port their solution to the standard syntax.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That makes sense. I guess that since so many people use `border-radius` that you can forget that it wasn't an actual standard until recently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is -moz-XXX and -webkit-XXX in the CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393168/why-there-is-moz-xxx-and-webkit-xxx-in-the-css3)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this question is essentially the same given here:

[Why there is -moz-XXX and -webkit-XXX in the CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393168/why-there-is-moz-xxx-and-webkit-xxx-in-the-css3)

> That "namespacing" allows vendors to test new cool features, and if
>   they're great, they can be incorporated into the standards. This is
>   what is happening [here]: Mozilla and the Webkit team tried cool
>   things, and now they're going to become standard. It's just not done
>   yet.

Comment: I would add that adding the browser-specific notation (`-moz`, `-webkit`) allows the browser vendor to later seemlessly (for the property) support a different, standard syntax, without breaking previous, non-standard implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, life isn't perfect. Ideally yes, it should be standardized. It's an old issue dealing with the various large companies/groups that develop browsers. [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) tries to make standards, but in the end you can't force anyone.

Try reading more at this very relevant SO.programmers page - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103048/why-is-it-unrealistic-to-expect-all-browsers-to-support-the-same-standards  . And more regarding browsers/compatibility [here](http://kb.siteground.com/article/Why_does_my_website_look_different_on_different_browsers.html),

Answer (score 1):

Eventually they will all support the standard `border-radius`. I'm given to understand they do that when things are up in the air standards-wise, or for similar reasons.

(also, no need for `-moz-border-radius`, the normal cross-browser is now supported by Gecko. I believe it's the same for WebKit too, but I'm too lazy to check.)

Comment: Newer Webkit browsers support CSS3 now.